# Element is not scrolled by mousewheel until clicked or focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, mousewheel

I have a scrollable element (`overflow-y: auto;`) in my HTML.

However, when you put mouse over it and start to use mousewheel it's not scrolling unless you click inside of it.

The only workaround I found was to add `tabindex="-1"` attribute to make the element focusable and then call `$element.focus()` when mousewheel events occur. This works to a some degree. However, when element is focused already, the `focus()` will not do anything and the element become unscrollable until you click outside of it and then click inside of it again. Also, I don't like this workaround because it will draw a focus border around the element.

What actually controls what element on the page receives the scrolling? The weird thing is that I can see that my element actually receives the mousewheel events, but it's not scrolling for some reason.

SO, how do I make sure that element is scrollable by mousewheel when mouse pointer is over it?

I'm testig it in Google Chrome.

Comment: could you provide some code and a example?

Comment: Do you have a clean version?  ie with no other code - possibly as a snippet in SO or on jsfiddle (or preferred alternative).  This would confirm you have no other code / 3rd party includes / addins etc interfering.  eg, given all the information you have provided, it works fine here:  https://jsfiddle.net/1kjoyzf7/   Does that work for you?  if so, you have something else getting the way.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that it's part of some complex frontend application. It will be difficult to extract the issue. I was hoping someone experienced the same problem, or is familiar with the mentioned symptoms.

Comment: Try to add `mouseover` event which will focus the element, to the element.

`$('element').on('mouseover', function(e){$(this).focus();});

Comment: @GangadharJannu the problem is — there are situations when element is focused, but not scrollable. In such case you have to click outside of the element and then back inside of it.